# Real-time update to NodeJS(MVC, Express), Mysql and Socket.io application

Tags: mysql, node.js, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I'm trying to create a real time web application with NodeJS with an MVC layout using the Express framework and MySQL as my back end data store.

The problem that I've run into is that I can't find any good examples or tutorials on how to use [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) (or any other web socket platform to pass information in real time from the database to the web application.  The specific problem is getting any new update to MySQL on a specific table to pass that information to, so that if new information is added to the database by a second client connection it will update on the first client connection as soon as the information is added.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get socket.io(or another websocket connection protocol) and mysql to work together to achieve this? Any code example's or pointing me to some websites that have documentation on this topic would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You should separate your logic to 2 parts: Update the database and Notice other users about the update. First thing is normal and no real-time needed here, second thing is real-time. You can find good socket.io examples at http://socket.io/#how-to-use . Another thing: express and socket.io can work together, but the relation between them is weak, why don't you try sails instead, it's implemented socket.io in it: http://sailsjs.com/

Comment: Same here. I can't find a good example or tutorial on it. I only found tutorials and examples of simple chat applications. Need help on this